# How can I upgrade eclipse helios?

Tags: upgrade, eclipse, helios

I tried to upgrade eclipse helios by `Help--> Check for updates`. But the progressing bar stops at 38% and never completes. `I'm developing php applications using this eclipse helios.` Can anyone suggest how can I upgrade this eclipse helios ?

```
I'm using windows 7 (64-bit) and my current eclipse version is 3.6.0
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have any plugins installed in your Eclipse, either from the Eclipse Marketplace or from other sources, there is a chance that you will break a plugin or lose functionality of a plugin if you upgrade your Eclipse. When you upgrade Eclipse, Eclipse doesn't check if the full functionality of every one of your plugins will be preserved. Then you'll have to find out about a plugin that isn't working the hard way after you find your code isn't working as expected. So it would be better if you backed up all your project data, and then did a fresh install of the latest version of Eclipse.

Comment: Thanks for the response. So can I use `eclipse Kepler` for php codings?

Comment: @Su123 The [PHP IDE project](http://projects.eclipse.org/projects/tools.pdt) delivers a PHP Integrated Development Environment framework for the Eclipse platform. This project encompasses the development components necessary to develop PHP-based Web Applications and facilitates extensibility. It leverages the existing Web Tools Project in providing developers with PHP capabilities.

Comment: Thank you very much. I downloaded a fresh copy of eclipse Kepler and installed it, then installed the PDT for it. Now it's working like a charm. Appreciate your suggestion +1